# Codename One - How to get a response after file upload with multipart request

Tags: java, vimeo, codenameone, vimeo-api

I'm using Codename One to upload videos to Vimeo using their respective API's. I'm using a multipart request to actually upload the file, but a response is required to find the upload status. How can I get the response?

```
public void doFileUpload(String url, String filename) throws IOException {
    MultipartRequest req = new MultipartRequest() {
        int chr;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        public String response = "";

        public void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            response = Util.readToString(input);

            Log.p("File Response->" + response);
        }

        protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message)
        {
            Log.p("Error Response->" + message);
        }

        protected void readHeaders(Object connection) throws IOException {
            String val = getHeader(connection, "MyHeaderName");
            Log.p("Header Response->" + val);

        }

        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
            Dialog.show(
                    "Connection Err!!",
                    "Are you connected to the internet? Check your connection",
                    "Ok", null);
        }
    };
    req.setUrl(url);
    req.setPost(true);

    String mime = "application/mp4";
    req.addData("file_data", filename, mime);
    req.setFilename("file_data", filename);
    req.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
    req.addResponseCodeListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                NetworkEvent event = (NetworkEvent) ev;
                Log.p("Err Rsp Code->" + event.getResponseCode());
                Log.p("ResponseCodeListener:");
                Log.p(ev.toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the addData method that accepts a file URL rather than a byte array since you might exceed device memory with the byte array version (e.g. for a larger video or low memory device).

You can read the response just like any other connection request:

1. Derive the connection request and override: `protected void readResponse(InputStream input)`
2. Use `addResponseListener` to bind a listener to the users response.
3. Use `addToQueueAndWait` to detect that the upload finished then just invoke `getResponseData()` to get the byte array data.

Comment: Hey Shai, thanks for the reply. Check the updated method. I'm still not getting a response.

Comment: In case this is an error response could be sent to the error stream so to read that too make sure to invoke setReadResponseForErrors(true). Also you might want to override the response code method as well to handle error codes.
On a different subject reading one byte at a time from the stream is REALLY slow! Try Util.readToString(InputStream).

Comment: Shai, I'm still not getting an error response. I've updated my code to the latest. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: What do you get in the logs? Do you get the response code? On which platforms did you test this?

Comment: Hey Shai, I'm not getting anything in the logs. Using a Windows machine. I'll go ahead and create an android app from the source files and see if I get anything that way.

Comment: None? Not even the error code log or the headers? Are you sure this code is executing properly?
Did you run it thru the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! on the back-end, I am using `Spring boot`, my upload controller was simply tagged as `@Controller` when changed to `@RestController`, it worked fine and I got `readResponse(InputStream input)` callback, where I handle the response as JSON.